# How can I use image lazy-loading in RN FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a FlatList, where the items are posts with their images and some texts. I don't want to render all images when the component is mounted. I want only load the images which are already seen. Is there any way to load only viewport images?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution for this. I used `onViewableItemsChanged` prop of `FlatList`. The logic is the following: with this prop you can see the items which are seen. You can register them properly (for example I add `postSeen: true` to each seen posts in the application state). That way you will have all changes under your hand and will be able to use them as needed. Hope this will help someone else.

If you have another solution for this, I will be happy to know. Thanks